# How to view changes made by last pull to my local files in github?

Tags: git, github, difference, pull

How to view changes made by last pull to my local files in github, in windows? The changes made by last pull may include changes made by multiple commits pulled at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the reflog of the *remote* branch to view the commit it was on before you pulled :

```
$ git reflog origin/master              # <- 'origin/master', not 'master'
3ab2281 refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: pull: fast-forward  # <-last pull
3cdd5d1 refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}: fetch: fast-forward # <-previous pull
cda1bbd refs/remotes/origin/master@{2}: fetch: fast-forward
5b18e70 refs/remotes/origin/master@{3}: fetch: fast-forward
...
```

You can then view the diff between the two last listed commits :

```
$ git diff 3cdd5d1 3ab2281         # usual diff in terminal
# or
$ git difftool -d 3cdd5d1 3ab2281  # graphical diff viewer
```

To simply view the list of modified files, along with a little flag `A`dded, `M`odified or `D`eleted :

```
$ git diff --name-status 3cdd5d1 3ab2281
M       .travis.yml
M       Documentation/RelNotes/2.10.2.txt
M       Documentation/RelNotes/2.11.0.txt
M       Documentation/config.txt
M       Documentation/diff-config.txt
...
```

---

[edit] the `origin/master@{xx}` are actually valid ways to point at "the `xx`th entry in the reflog", so you can also run :

```
git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master
git difftool -d origin/master@{1} origin/master
git diff --name-status origin/master@{1} origin/master
...
```